# TypeError: null reference error

Tags: javascript, typeerror

I'm learning codeacademy javascript codes and I really not understand why it gives me this error:

> TypeError: Unable to get property 'magazine' of undefined or null reference

1. Write the add method which has a single parameter, itemCost. It will add the itemCost to the total.
2. We have partially written the scan method for you and started a switch statement. Add the following 2 items to the switch statement:

   - "magazine", 4.99
   - "chocolate", 0.45

Finally, use the scan method to buy 2 eggs and 3 magazines.

```
var cashRegister = {
    total: 0,

    add: function(itemCost) {
        itemCost += total
    },

    scan: function(item) {
        switch (item) {
            case "eggs":
                this.add(0.98);
                break;

            case "milk":
                this.add(1.23);
                break;

                //Add other 2 items here
            case 'magazine':
                this.add(4.99);
                break;
            case 'chocolate':
                this.add(0.45);
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
};


cashRegister.sacan['eggs', 'eggs', 'magazine', 'magazine']

console.log('Your bill is ' + cashRegister.total);
```

Comment: `scan` is an function, not an array. but you call it like an array `cashRegister.sacan['eggs', 'eggs', 'magazine', 'magazine']`

Comment: @shakhrillo You are using `.sacan` not `.scan`.

Comment: few problems. 1. `typo` while calling `cashRegister.scan` . 2. `scan` function will work with string or number, while you are defining it as array (even the brackets are missing, you are passing an array)

Comment: You also need to swap total+=itemCost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you got most of the bits right, but you've got a typo and are using the scan function incorrectly in a few ways.

Functions in Javascript are caleld with parentheses, not brackets as you have them.  Additionally, the scan() function takes a single item as a parameter, not an array (or multiple parameters).

So to scan one 'eggs', the code would look like this:

```
cashRegister.scan('eggs');
```

That should get you back on track.

Comment: And it would be elegant to have shop = { eggs:0.98, milk...}

Comment: this time It gives me ReferenceError: 'total' is undefined

Comment: @mplungjan: It's part of a coding exercise, not the time for optimization :)

Comment: You've resolved the question at hand, and SO isn't the place to debug your program line-by-line.  Look at the line numbers of the errors, read up on JS, use the debug console, and perhaps look to an IRC channel or chat room for further help.  I'd recommend the SO chatrooms, but you need more rep to join in there.

Comment: I do not like switches :) `scan: function(item) {
  this.add({eggs:0.98,milk:1.23,magazine:4.99,chocolate:0.45}[item]);
}`

Comment: @mplungjan Fair enough, but again, this is a coding exercise where OP is just learning Javascript.  This is a context for clear, straightforward code, not optimized but less readable code.

Comment: Of course it is an exercise. If my object is moved outside the function I think this is more readable than a switch: `scan: function(item) { this.add(shop[item]); }` - amiright?

Answer (score 0):

Your code has many errors. If you want to get total value then try the following code.

[This is a](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide) good place to start learning javascript.

```
<script>
var cashRegister = {
    total: 0,

    add: function(itemCost) {
        this.total += itemCost;
    },

    scan: function(item) {
        switch (item) {
            case "eggs":
                this.add(0.98);
                break;

            case "milk":
                this.add(1.23);
                break;

                //Add other 2 items here
            case 'magazine':
                this.add(4.99);
                break;
            case 'chocolate':
                this.add(0.45);
                break;
        }
    }
};
cashRegister.scan('eggs');
cashRegister.scan('eggs');
cashRegister.scan('magazine');
cashRegister.scan('magazine');

alert('Your bill is ' + cashRegister.total);

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
var cashRegister = {
total:0,

//insert the add method here    
add: function(itemCost){
    this.total += itemCost;
},

scan: function(item) {
    switch (item) { 
    case "eggs": 
        this.add(0.98); 
        break;

    case "milk": 
        this.add(1.23); 
        break;

    //Add other 2 items here
    case "magazine":
        this.add(4.99);
        break;

    case "chocolate":
        this.add(0.45);
        break;
    }
    return true;
   }
 };

//Scan 2 eggs and 3 magazines
cashRegister.scan("eggs");
cashRegister.scan("eggs");
cashRegister.scan("magazine");
cashRegister.scan("magazine");
cashRegister.scan("magazine");

//Show the total bill
console.log('Your bill is '+cashRegister.total);
```